# What are unexpected text nodes?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent Element containing just one child element so as far as I know this parent element has one child node but in console there are three nodes two of them is text node. This is clear in this image.

[image: unexpected text node in javascript]

Now my questions are:

1. Where do these text nodes come from?
2. Are these text nodes built in? What is the necessity of them?
3. What are the rules of them?

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var children = container.childNodes;
console.log(children);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id='test'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, I draw a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GbLI.png) with two different colors to show what are those two other text nodes. If you don't want to see that two text nodes, after you get the element, you'd better do some html minify before calling childNodes. For example, you won't see them with `<div id="container"><div id='test'></div></div>` as html element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two of the `childNodes` are newlines. From MDN:

> `childNodes` includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead.

See the output of the below snippet, if you do not understand what I mean:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var chlds = container.childNodes;
chlds.forEach(c => console.log(c.nodeName + ":" + c.innerText));
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id='test'></div>
</div>
```

To answer your follow-up questions, the text nodes are there as they exist in the document, due to the document having newlines (or other non-element markup). `children` is a far more reliable way to get the child nodes of an element, as `childNodes` output can vary between unminified and minified HTML code, which could cause you some headaches.

Comment: I understand what `forEach` does but what does `c =>` do? There's no `c` variable initialized here, so I completely don't understand this line `(c => console.log(c.nodeName + ":" + c.innerText))`

Comment: @Shayan `c => console.log(c.nodeName + ":" + c.innerText)` is the equivalent of writing `function(c){ console.log(c.nodeName + ":" + c.innerText) }`. It's a new syntax for functions called arrow functions, look it up, it's quite nice!